Blender to Unity - Normals Seriously Messed Up?

I've been using Blender and Unity for awhile now and this is the first time I have had this happen. As you can see the Faces on the Model are correct, they are on the outside of the mesh. But in Unity (just the face) is some how inside out. I have tried flipping the normals to see if it would maybe fix the issue but it looks even more inside out. It's like the outer shell of the model doesn't exists or something. Did I click something in Blender that causes this issue? This head took me 8 hours to sculpt and rig (the model itself took a whole 2 days). Really would hate to loose all that work. Any ideas?
The only thing I remember in the earlier stages when I was checking the faces, it started off showing they were indeed inside out (So I flipped them to be outside) everything else went smoothly. But I cant help but wonder if I must have clicked something accidentally to cause this. The faces are perfectly fine in Blender, but when taken into Unity it's like the outer shell doesn't exist, even if I flip the face, it simply doesn't change it and makes it look even worst.Any ideas?

Have you tried resetting the normals in Blender (Alt N-> Reset Vectors)? Also, what format did you export the model from Blender as?
